# Qt Creator: error with SHGetSpecialFolderPath while building any example

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, directory

I'm trying to build one of Qt examples in Qt Creator and give an error with SHGetSpecialFolderPath:

```
Starting: "C:\ALL\QtSrc\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\ALL\QtSrc\Examples\Qt-5.6\qtdeclarative\quick\demos\calqlatr\calqlatr.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
SHGetSpecialFolderPath() failed for standard location "16", clsid=0x1c. (??????? ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.)
```

I found that clsid with value 0x1c is the path to CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, which also contains the user name, and on my machine it consists of non-ASCII symbols (Russian letters).
May be a problem in this? Is there any way to resolve it without renaming the folder with an user name?

Comment: IInspectable, I haven't got any code, I'm just trying to build an example

Comment: You've got no code? Did you just type that text into the question?

Comment: David Heffernan, it is error in console output of Qt Creator, assert has catched during qmake running on all the examples that I has tried to build

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, IInspectable the OP is trying to build the examples that come with Qt; in this case, the "calqlatr" example. That being said, this is probably a bug in `qmake` itself...

Comment: As I previously noted, if you're looking for a quality framework, you cannot seriously consider Qt. For the most part, Qt ships untested for anything outside mainstream setups. Expect bugs, lots of bugs, and little to no support (professional support).